# matlab numerical approximation, plotting a function of multivariable

Tags: matlab, function

First of all, this is a homework assignment where I'm actually trying to replicate Young's slit experiment, I realize that this might belong to the physics forum, but my question is involving a numerical approximation, which I can't make work.

What I want to do is to have a function of four variables, (x,y,xp,yp) and I want to integrate those with respect to x and y, both from -infinity to infinity, which means that:

f(x,y,xp,yp)-->q(xp,yp)

My f is a function which should look like the function f in my code. When I have q = @(xp,yp), I want to put a constant yp, lets say yp=0 --> b = @(xp) q(xp,0), and then I want to plot b against xp, you can look at my code below to see a little bit of what I want to do, but obviously it doesnt work. In my code I'm actually integrating from -50 to 50, simply to make the program work a bit faster.

```
clear all;
clc
l=1.45;
lambda = 650*10^-9;
f = @(x,y,xp,yp) exp((1i*2*pi/lambda)*sqrt((xp-x).^2 +(yp-y).^2 +l.^2));
xp = linspace(-10,10,20)
q = @(xp,yp) integral2(f,-50,50,-50,50)
b=@(xp) q(xp,0)
plot(xp,abs(b).^2)
```

I cant seem to make this work, anyone got any advice for me?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that my biggest issue is the line q=@(xp,yp) integral2(f,-50,50,-50,50). Because when I try to evaluate for 3,3, lets say c=q(3,3) I get an error back, is there a way for me to avoid this?

Comment: `q = @(xp,yp) integral2(f,-50,50,-50,50)` should be `q = @(xp,yp) integral2(@(x,y) f(x,y,xp,yp),-50,50,-50,50)`. Though I do not know if that is the only thing (My Matlab is unavailable at the moment).

Comment: Your right, I changed that and actually made it work by also putting "ArrayValue", true in that as well, thanks for the help in the right direction!